# Ceph status health ok, but has flag "nearfull"

Tags: storage, ceph

Recently in Ceph there was a status of WARN because 3 disks were 85-87% full. I expanded the cluster by adding the server to the storage. But now I see flag "nearfull". Previously, this wasn't see.

```
 health HEALTH_OK
 monmap e6: 3 mons at {mon1=10.10.10.2:6789/0,mon2=10.10.10.3:6789/0,mon3=10.10.10.4:6789/0}
        election epoch 14298, quorum 0,1,2 mon1,mon2,mon3
 osdmap e212153: 138 osds: 138 up, 138 in
        flags nearfull
  pgmap v72003723: 6656 pgs, 4 pools, 25984 GB data, 7231 kobjects
        78180 GB used, 44126 GB / 119 TB avail
            6656 active+clean
client io 1188 kB/s rd, 15303 kB/s wr, 764 op/s
```

We use Ceph Hammer. But one new node is Jewel. We plan to update Ceph.

Do I need to do something? Does this affect the storage? Or everything is OK?

Comment: Could you please share "ceph osd df" listing?

Comment: @Strepsils, https://clck.ru/DoumP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "CEPH health detail" show you HEALTH_OK, don't worry about it, but try restart one by one monitor and then OSD's. Looks like that flag is just hung. In case if the flag was real the CEPH health will alarm because of it.